# X, Y, XY why does this work in gcc?

Tags: c

Why does this code work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define X 1
#define Y 2

int main(){

    int XY = XY;

    printf("%d\n", XY);

    return 0;

}
```

It prints a garbage value and no errors.

I suppose this is UB?

I tested this code on mac OS, brew gcc 7.1.0.

It seems other users of gcc are experiencing similar results.

Comment: The defines are irrelevant. You're effectively asking about `int x = x;`.

Comment: yes, it's UB. `XY` is just a variable initialized from itself. The macros have nothing to do with it.

Comment: What is the problem? You initialize a variable with itself uninitialized. Yes, it is undefined. Has nothing to do with the macros.

Comment: You need to learn how tokens work in C.

Comment: @PSkocik You are right. If I change XY to another arbitrary variable name such as a or b, it still works. Why no error with gcc? Some users say that clang spits 'Uninitialized error'.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot. I'll definitely check out tokens.

Comment: @DaehyunKim `gcc` indeed misses this error while `clang` catches it: `warning: variable 'XY' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization [-Wuninitialized]`

Comment: Also how to concatenate the results of macros, if you had a valid reason to do so.

Comment: @DaehyunKim as this code doesn't violate a constraint, a compiler is *allowed* to remain silent on it. But in any case, *the behavior is undefined* ;) `clang` just does a better job here with the warnings.

Comment: In what sense does this "work", then?

Comment: @FelixPalmen That is very interesting. Wow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's undefined behavior to use the value of an uninitialized (auto) variable that could have been declared with the `register` keyword (see [6.3.2.1p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p2) in the C standard).

`int XY;` could have been declared with `register` (you're not taking its address anywhere) and it's still unitialized at the right hand side of `int XY = XY;`, so the behavior is undefined.

If you did `int XY = *&XY;` the behavior would no longer be undefined, but `XY` would get an indeterminate value.

Comment: Why `register` is relevant here?

Comment: @EugeneSh. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p2

Comment: and even if there was some code taking a pointer, it would still be an initialization from an indeterminate value ... so still impossible to tell anything about the result (except it doesn't do something completely different like formatting a harddisk)

Comment: Are you saying that the `register` keyword is making the use of indeterminate value to be UB, while without it it is not UB?

Comment: @EugeneSh. well, with an object actually stored in a register, this object doesn't really exist before it has a value, I guess that's the rationale for making its usage UB

Comment: @FelixPalmen: And in C++ (which throws off the shackles of implementation-driven abstraction leaks) that is true of literally any object, odr-used or not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit which is a sensible thing to do (and it's rare I feel that way about C++ ... hehe, scnr)

Comment: @FelixPalmen I am not quite seeing how the register storage is different from a non-register in this case. Can't we (compiler) say "Let XY to be stored in R1 register, and initialize it from the R1 value"?

Comment: ... and passing an indeterminate value to a library function - even without trap representations - would have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That would require the compiler to needlessly block a register before there's a value to store. When you never take a pointer to some local variable, the compiler might decide to put it in a register for optimization, but having to block this register for the whole scope probably wouldn't be optimal

Comment: @EugeneSh. there are implementations in which the registers have hw The C standard allows this to work without explicit initialization of the registers.